# Hub.Header template

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-8.1

I want to create template for Hub, because I need complicated `StackPanel` in Header, but I can't figure out how to do it. First of All I wanted to check `TextBlock` control, so I wrote three sample styles:

```
<Style x:Key="HubSectionStyle" TargetType="HubSection">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="With Style1">
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="HubSectionStyle2" TargetType="HubSection">
    <Setter Property="Header">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>With Style2</TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="HubSectionStyle3" TargetType="HubSection">
    <Setter Property="Header">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <TextBlock>With Style3</TextBlock>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And tried this way:

```
<HubSection>
    <HubSection.Header>
        <TextBlock>Without Style</TextBlock>
    </HubSection.Header>
</HubSection>

<HubSection Style="{StaticResource HubSectionStyle}">
</HubSection>

<HubSection Style="{StaticResource HubSectionStyle2}">
</HubSection>

<HubSection Style="{StaticResource HubSectionStyle3}">
</HubSection>
```

As a result I've four columns with following headers:

> Without Style,
>   With Style1,
>   Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate,
>   Windows.UI.Xaml.ControlTemplate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `HeaderTemplate` to define Template for Header..

```xml
<Style x:Key="HubSectionStyle2" TargetType="HubSection">
  <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock>With Style2</TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Get more details about `HeaderTemplate` you can get [here..](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hubsection.headertemplate.aspx)